# How Do You Write Output To File Inside Function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I want to write out live values that are produced from the function below to a text file. How can I achieve that?

```
def run(readable_results, data, rawbuf):
    output = open("output.txt", "a", 0)
    if(len(readable_results) > 1 or len(readable_results) == 0):
        output.write('no response')
    elif('weather' in readable_results):
        output.write('weather')
    elif('news' in readable_results):
        output.write('news')
    elif('video' in readable_results):
        output.write('video')
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? Other than the fact that you never close the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just made a simple logic error in

```
if(len(readable_results) > 1 ... ):
```

I mean, yeah.
Anyway, I wrote your code and gave it a test

```
file = "./output.txt"

def run(readable_results, data, rawbuf):
    output = open(file, "a")
    if(len(readable_results) < 1 or len(readable_results) == 0):  #just flipped the comparison operator
        output.write('no response')
    elif('weather' in readable_results):
        output.write('weather')
    elif('news' in readable_results):
        output.write('news')
    elif('video' in readable_results):
        output.write('video')
    output.write("\n")
    output.close()      # don't forget to close files

run("Hello World! news", 0, 0)
```

and it writes to the file no problem (given the file is in the same path as the .py you're executing). Hope this helped

Comment: `if x < 1 or x == 0:` is redundant. Just do `if x < 1:`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code.. maybe you should close the file that u r working on.....
Then change the ..
         if(len(readable_results) > 1 or len(readable_results) == 0):
To 
          if(len(readable_results) < 1: